# How to made a system on two weeks or less?

Tags: java, android, e-commerce

I'm a Senior Java programmer, with more than 7 years of experience, and lately, I'm using Google App Engine to build cloud software, usually, using frameworks like Spring, Objectify, Apache Tiles, etc... I'm even working on some android native app...

I think I'm good at this, for example, I did a complete billing system in two months all by myself; but the last days I've received a few disappointing comments from my boss who claims to know a guy "recently graduated of high-school" who can do the same as I do in two weeks or less (android apps, complete e-commerce systems, etc).

I'm wondering if I'm missing something... ¿there is a way to do it on such time? Maybe I'm little old and I'm doing it in a old way... are there a framework or programming language that you can recommend me?

Comment: My first question, is your boss a software developer?? Good software is not made in two weeks, unless you are spending very little time doing anything else with your time, life, etc. If a kid right out of high school is able to build a complete system in two weeks OR less, then I'd venture to say that kid is very talented, no one can do this.

Comment: Your boss doesn't seem to be a programmer. It's not about speed.

Comment: Your boss doesn't seem to be smart. Don't worry and look another opotunities where your boss will appreciate you.

Comment: don't care about your boss. you can easily find another job as an experienced programmer.

Comment: Thanks LucasCrawford, keyser and DontRelaX, obviously my boss is not a software developer and knows nothing about it, but I'm always looking this kind of challenges to improve myself... I'm afraid to get used to do things always in the same way and don't learn new forms of do it faster and better

Comment: Your boss doesn't know what he's talking about.  You could possibly set up a bunch of off the shelf components in that time with no customization, no testing, no integration with existing business systems, no security, etc.  Not a customized maintainable solution.  Really your boss sounds like a manager from Dilbert.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can create something like that in 2 weeks or less. I means sure you can install a pre-made system or add an e-commerce add on to Joomla or drupal.

But that is premade and has no customization. Off course graduates will know more about the latest systems and will work with the latest stuff.

When you become a programmer you have to make a commitment to keep an eye on new developments and try out the latest stuff to keep up to date. Staying with the same methods will cause you too come to a standstill, but that off course does not mean you write bad code or the system doesn't work.

Your manager should know that you can never complete a full system in 2 weeks if you want it to be secure and fully tested...